# fgets and non-printable characters

Tags: c, io

Can fgets read non-printable characters into the given char* (it appears I can't)?  And if not, what is the alternative that would allow a maximum number of input characters from a stream into a char*?

**EDIT** (for my particular case)

I have an encoder that prints "Le\D7" to stdout, which is piped to a decoder which grabs that from its stdin using:

```
if( fgets( inputChars, MAX_BYTES_IN, stdin ) == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Trouble getting input\n" );
    return 0;
}

while( inputChars[crntChar] != '\0' && inputChars[crntChar] != '\n' )
{
    printf( "Value %d: %d\n", crntChar, inputChars[crntChar]);
    crntChar++;
}
```

This results in:

```
Value 0: 76
Value 1: 101
Value 2: -41
```

Using fgetc has the same result

Comment: Which characters does it appear to fail to read?

Comment: You can use fread http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: ASCII value 198 doesn't go through.  The character read has a huge integer value

Comment: There is no such thing as ASCII 198.  Show your code.  Maybe there's a signed->unsigned conversion in there we can spot.

Comment: there will be a signed->unsigned conversion if ascii 198 is being represented in a `char` instead of `int` or `short` or even `unsigned char`

Comment: I mean when I do ((unsigned int) someChar), that's the value I get

Comment: @vlad417 what's the problem? If you got the value 198 from a `FILE *` into `someChar` then you've actually _read_ the character.

Comment: casting maybe can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a weird value because of the unsigned to signed integer conversion.

```
char x = 198;

printf("x = %d\n", x);
printf("(unsigned) x = %u\n", (unsigned) x);
printf("(unsigned char) x = %d\n", (unsigned char) x);
```

Output:

```
x = -58
(unsigned) x = 4294967238
(unsigned char) x = 198
```

The `(unsigned char)` cast is what you want.

Please ignore the signed overflow in my code.  Note that if you compile using GCC and the `-funsigned-char` flag, the output is:

```
x = 198
(unsigned) x = 198
(unsigned char) x = 198
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it.  I go through the char* after fgets and cast it all to unsigned chars.  Could also cast fgetc I'd imagine.

Comment: @vlad417: `fgetc()` does not need a cast, since it uses the `(unsigned char)` conversion internally.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use `fgetc()`. `fgets()` internally relies on `fgetc()`.

But there are many alternatives, `fread()` being one of them. `fscanf()`.

`fgetc()` and others read both printable and non-printable characters into a `char` array. A `char` is just a 1 byte number encoded in ASCII(or 2 bytes in case of `wchar_t`). There is no concept of `printable` and `non printable` character in C.

Comment: I think there is *some* idea of printable versus non-printable character, since there's an `isprint` function in `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: the _some_ idea is for human readers not machine reading :-) @templatetypedef

Comment: There is a concept of printable / nonprintable characters in C.  The C standard specifies a macro or function `isprint()`, which returns true for characters that are printable, and false for non-printable characters.  It is available in the `<ctype.h>` header.

Comment: so, @DietrichEpp does `fgetc()` read non-printable characters in a different way than it reads printable characters?

Comment: No, but the answer says "There is no concept of printable and non printable character in C" and this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` will read one line of string, in this case read until new line `\n` / `0x0A` or `NULL` / `EOF`.

or maybe you can use unsigned char* for non printable ASCII.

so in my opinion, yes `fgets()` can read non printable ASCII